# ASP.NET C# System.NullReferenceException on requesting cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem when I request cookies, but I don't understand what I can do to solve it.

My code:

```
public partial class Admin_LogIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminPassword"] != null && Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"] != null)
            if ("***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminPassword"].Value.ToString()) && "***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value.ToString()))
                Response.Redirect("Benvenuto.aspx");
    }
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserTextBox.Text == "***" && PasswordTextBox.Text == "***")
        {
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value = UserTextBox.Text;
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"].Value = PasswordTextBox.Text;
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "0.1;Benvenuto.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            GeneralErrorTextBox.Text = "Nome utente e/o password errata!";
        }
    }
}
```

So I have tried this to fix it:

```
public partial class Admin_LogIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var adminuser = Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"];
        var adminpassword = Request.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"];
        if (adminuser != null && adminpassword != null)
            if ("***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminPassword"].Value.ToString()) && "***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value.ToString()))
                Response.Redirect("Benvenuto.aspx");
    }
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserTextBox.Text == "***" && PasswordTextBox.Text == "***")
        {
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value = UserTextBox.Text;
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"].Value = PasswordTextBox.Text;
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            Response.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
            Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "0.1;Benvenuto.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            GeneralErrorTextBox.Text = "Nome utente e/o password errata!";
        }
    }
}
```

But I always get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>     Admin_LogIn.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +126
>     System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>     System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>     System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
> ```
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1016

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you storing username/password as clear text? Worrying....

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you try to use a property or call a method of an object that is null. More details:

A simple use of Visual studio DEBUGGER can tell you the object because of which it is happening. Just look at the stack trace and put a debugger on that line. Check the objects of that line and see if any one is null and you are trying to use that objects property. Handle the same.

Comment: It says to me that is the lane in which there is
"***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminPassword"].Value.ToString()) && "***".Equals(Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value.ToString())
but before they pass the "if(adminuser!=null && adminpassword!=null)"

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong but it looks like you've wrongly named one of your cookie items. You call it:

```
var adminpassword = Request.Cookies["IvoucherAdminCookiePassword"];
```

But on the next line, you reference the `IvoucherCookieAdminPassword`.

So, is it `CookieAdminPassword` or `AdminCookiePassword` or both?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not setting the value of

```
Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminPassword"].Value **and** Request.Cookies["IvoucherCookieAdminMail"].Value
```

while you are making check on them in **Page_Load** function when they contain null,before make a condition you have to set their value.

to view more deatils on **.Equal()** please see,
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx
Read more about HttpRequest.Cookies Property go to .... 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx

Happy Coding.......